# Why does it take so much time for R to compute m for loop with basic calculations?

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop, simulation

Why does the computation of the following code in R take so much time? It takes many minutes, so I have interruped the calculations.

My aim is to adapt my simulated random numbers (`sumzv`, dim(sumzv) = 1000000 x 10) to my market model `S_t` (geometric brownian motion).
The vectors `m` and `s` describe the drift and the deviation of the GBM and are vectors containing 10 numbers. `DEL` is the variable for the time steps. `S_0` is a vector containing 10 stock prices at time 0.

```
n <- 1000000
k <- 10

S_t <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = k))

i <- 1
j <- 1
t <- 10

for (j in 1:k) {
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    S_t[i, j] <- S_0[j] * exp(m[j] * t * DEL + s[j] * sqrt(DEL) * sumzv[i, j])
  
  }
  
}
```

Thank you for your help. Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner :)

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any helpful information so far on the internet. Some pages said, vectorization is helpful to speed up an R Code, but this doesn't seem helpful to me.
I tried to break down the data frames into vectors but this got very complex.

Comment: What is object `DEL` please?  Also you should not include `i <- i+1` in your loops, the loop will handle that for you, and R does not require semicolons `;` at end of rows.

Comment: your `S_t <- ...` line is also missing a closing `)`.

Comment: Also missing are `S_0` and `sumzv`.

Comment: `DEL = (1/257)` is the variable for the time steps. 
Unfortunately, I didn't copy the closing `)`, when I wrote my question. Sorry. In my code the brackets are all closed.

Comment: `sumzv` = simulated random numbers (dim(sumzv) = 1000000 x 10)
`S_0` is a vector of 10 stock prices (stock price for time t = 0)

Comment: Thanks for the values. Now it's `m[j]` that is wrong, `m` is the scalar number of columns of `S_t` and `m[2] == m[3] == etc == NA`. And `t` is also missing.

Comment: I think that also `t` and `s` are missing. if I well understood `t` should be a scalar and `s` a vector

Comment: The vectors `m` and `s` describe the drift and the deviation of the GBM. They are just vectors with each 10 numbers. `t = 10`

Comment: then you have used m as a vector of 10 numbers and also as one of your indexes, which will be causing a conflict.

Comment: I named the integer `m` and the vector `m` the same but it is another accident when I copied the code.

Comment: I edited my question and included all your comments! Thank you! And sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 4):

The following code with vectorized inner loop is equivalent to the posted code.
It also pre-computes some inner loop vectors, `fac1` and `fac2`.

```
S_t <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = m))
fac1 <- m * t * DEL
fac2 <- s * sqrt(DEL)
for (j in 1:k) {
  S_t[, j] <- S_0[j] * exp(fac1[j] + fac2[j] * sumzv[, j])
}
```

The *fully* vectorized version of the loop on `j` above is the one-liner below. The transposes are needed because R is column major and we are multiplying by row vectors indexed on `j = 1:k`.

```
S_t2 <- t(S_0 * exp(fac1 + fac2 * t(sumzv)))
```

Comment: FYI the OP has clarified that the m in the inner loop is a vector of 10 values, not the `m <- 10` from the start of the code block. edit: you've already updated :D

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Thanks, I had not noticed the edit to the question and posted wrong code, then corrected it.

Comment: I got the concept and it works out! Thanks a lot